# Data visualization: Choropleth map not displaying color

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, geojson, choropleth

I just get started with data visualization and now I want to create a choropleth map show the number of soccer play in Premiere League.

I use python 3.8.5 and have a dataset in a CSV file. I try to create a choropleth map using plotly. After that, I created a choropleth, but my problem is the map didn't show any color, it only showed the earth form.

The code is here: https://github.com/quockhanhcao/Question

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


country = json.load(open("countries.geojson", "r"))
df = pd.read_csv('forward_country.csv')
country_code_map = {}

#map the code in geojson file of each country in csv file
for feature in country['features']:
    feature['code'] = feature['properties']['ISO_A3']
    country_code_map[feature['properties']['ADMIN']] = feature['code']
df['code'] = df['Country'].apply(lambda x: country_code_map[x])


fig = px.choropleth(df, locations='code', geojson=country, color = 'Number')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Can you please add your code to you question. Don't post a link. And please the output, two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to link the country abbreviation name to GeoJson's ISO_A3.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quockhanhcao/Question/main/countries.geojson') as response:
    country = json.load(response)

# country = json.load(open("./data/countries.geojson", "r"))
df = pd.read_csv('./data/forward_country.csv')
country_code_map = {}

#map the code in geojson file of each country in csv file
for feature in country['features']:
    feature['code'] = feature['properties']['ISO_A3']
    country_code_map[feature['properties']['ADMIN']] = feature['code']
df['code'] = df['Country'].apply(lambda x: country_code_map[x])

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=country,
                    locations='code',
                    featureidkey="properties.ISO_A3",
                    color='Number')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. So i just need to add featureidkey = "properties.ISO_A3" to list of argument of choropleth, right??

Comment: That's the point of the fix. However, the geojson file could not be read correctly, so I switched to URL reference. I've also modified the data path to my environment.